# Python Extract Blank From List

Tags: python, python-3.x, matching

I am new to Python and I might be doing this completely wrong.

I want to extract items from a file and then save them to a CSV which is fine except when there is a blank my list skips it and then when the list is displayed it moves all the items in that list up one and the items are not related to each other any more.

The items in the logfile can come through in different orders which stop me from saving the items based on order.

Thanks

```
mylist = []
modelCode = []
vin =[]
color=[]


with open('testfile_test.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if "Car Details" in line:
            split_line = line.split(',')
            for text in split_line:
                if "modelCode"in text:
                    split_line, split_line2 = text.split(' ',1)
                    modelCode.append(split_line2)
                else:
                    modelCode.append("")
                   #for items in modelCode:
                    #print(modelCode)
                    #var modelCodeTitle.append(split_line)
                if "vin"in text:
                    split_line, split_line2 = text.split(' ',1)
                    vin.append(split_line2)
                else:
                    vin.append("")
                if "color"in text:
                    split_line, split_line2 = text.split(' ',1)
                    color.append(split_line2)
                else:
                    color.append("")
with open("newfilename.csv", 'a') as outcsv:   
    #configure writer to write standard csv file
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Vin', 'Model Code', 'Colour', 'Chassis', 'Starting Location', 'Owning Organization', 'Final Organization'])
    #for item in modelCode:
    #for i, val in enumerate(modelCode):
    for a, b, c in zip_longest(vin, modelCode, color):
        #Write item to outcsv
        writer.writerow([a,b,c])
```

Sample Input:

> Hello World00:00:00.179 INFO  [CommandExecutionEngine] starting transaction
>   22.08.2017 00:15:27.549 INFO  [COMMAND] Car Details,additionalID ,vin EFG123456789, modelCode NEW XTRAIL MY17
>
> 22.08.2017 00:15:29.001 INFO  [COMMAND] Car Details,additionalID, chassis 54715, vin ABC123324679,modelCode JUKE FACELIFT,
>
> 22.08.2017 00:15:35.413 INFO  [COMMAND] Car Details,additionalID, vin ABC258741258,modelCode JUKE FACELIFT
>
> 22.08.2017 08:10:28.169 INFO  [COMMAND] Car Details,additionalID, chassis 25417, vin KFE456985234,modelCode NEW GALAXY,color BLUE
>
> 22.08.2017 08:10:28.503 INFO  [COMMAND] Car Details,additionalID, vin BFE874512458,modelCode MONDEO 5D,color SILVER
>
> 22.08.2017 08:10:28.810 INFO  [COMMAND] Car Details, vin ABC123456789,modelCode CONNECT V,color SILVER

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSuDO.png)

Comment: please provide a sample input and expected output. It would be easier to debug then

Comment: Can you show a sample of input which has this issue, and a sample of input which does not? Just a line or two for each should be fine.

Comment: Can you also provide an input with every field in it? Like `'Vin', 'Model Code', 'Colour', 'Chassis', 'Starting Location', 'Owning Organization', 'Final Organization'`. I need to see how they are given in the input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting all of these blanks is because you are appending blanks each time you check "text" to see which detail it is, even though you haven't moved to a new line.

For the line "22.08.2017 00:15:29.001 INFO [COMMAND] Car Details,additionalID, chassis 54715, vin ABC123324679,modelCode JUKE FACELIFT," the text "vin ABC123324679" will cause ABC123324679 to be appended to vin, but it will also cause blanks to be appended to modelCode and color.  You need to wait until you know that the item is missing from the entire line, not just the current text, before you add the blank.

The most minimal change to your code is to use the length of the lists to detect whether the line contained the desired detail.

```
with open('testfile_test.txt') as input_file:
    # Can't use enumerate because we skip blank lines.
    car = 0
    for line in input_file:
        if "Car Details" in line:
            split_line = line.split(',')
            for text in split_line:
                if "modelCode"in text:
                    split_line, split_line2 = text.split(' ',1)
                    modelCode.append(split_line2)
                if "vin"in text:
                    split_line, split_line2 = text.split(' ',1)
                    vin.append(split_line2)
                if "color"in text:
                    split_line, split_line2 = text.split(' ',1)
                    color.append(split_line2)
            if len(modelCode) < car:
                modelCode.append("")
            if len(vin) < car:
                vin.append("")
            if len(color) < car:
                color.append("")
            car += 1
```

This is not the approach I'd recommend, just useful to see why you're getting the blanks here.

Here's what I'd recommend:

```
import csv
cars = []


with open('testfile_test.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if "Car Details" in line:
            car = {}
            split_line = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]
            for text in split_line:
                detail = text.split(' ', 1)
                if len(detail) == 2:
                    car[detail[0]] = detail[1]
            cars.append(car)

with open("newfilename.csv", 'a') as outcsv:   
    # configure writer to write standard csv file
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([
        'Vin', 'Model Code', 'Colour', 'Chassis', 'Starting Location',
        'Owning Organization', 'Final Organization'])
    for car in cars:
        writer.writerow([
            car.get('vin', ''), car.get('modelCode', ''),
            car.get('color', '')])
```

This way

- Each car is represented by a dict containing all the details in the file, which makes it convenient to access the details for an individual car
- You don't have to special-case each detail, since they're all formatted the same way.
- The missing details are handled at output time instead of at parsing time, by using dict.get().

Comment: Thank you for both solutions and description of how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or even creating a class instead of using three lists. This will allow you more control over your data and your code will be easier to understand.

Try this:

```
# this will be a list of dictionaries
car_details = []


with open('testfile_test.txt') as input_file:

    for line in input_file:

        if "Car Details" in line:

            split_line = line.split(',')

            for text in split_line:

                # this is your dict object
                current_car = {}

                if "modelCode" in text:
                    # You can use index instead of creating a object that you will not use
                    current_car['modelCode'] = text.split(' ',1)[1]
                else:
                    current_car['modelCode'] = ''

                if "vin" in text:
                    current_car['vin'] = text.split(' ',1)[1]
                else:
                    current_car['vin'] = ''

                if "color" in text:
                    current_car['color'] = text.split(' ',1)[1]
                else:
                    current_car['color'] = ''

                car_details.append(current_car)


with open("newfilename.csv", 'a') as outcsv:   

    # configure writer to write standard csv file
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Vin', 'Model Code', 'Colour', 'Chassis', 'Starting Location', 'Owning Organization', 'Final Organization'])

    for car_detail in car_details:
        # Write item to outcsv
        writer.writerow([car_detail['vin'], car_detail['modelCode'], car_detail['Colour']])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code using `dictionaries`. In the following code, we are not checking whether certain field exists or not.

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

total_list = []
with open('testfile_test.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if "Car Details" in line:
            car_details = dict.fromkeys(['vin','modelCode','color','chassis','Starting Location','Owning Organization','Final Organization'],'')
            split_line = line.split(',')
            for text in split_line[1:]:
                value= text.strip().split(' ',1)
                if len(value)>1:
                    car_details[value[0]]=value[1]
            total_list.append(car_details)

with open("newfilename.csv", 'a') as outcsv:   
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Vin', 'Model Code', 'Colour', 'Chassis', 'Starting Location', 'Owning Organization', 'Final Organization'])
    for detail in total_list:
        writer.writerow([detail['vin'],detail['modelCode'],detail['color'],detail['chassis'],detail['Starting Location'],detail['Owning Organization'],detail['Final Organization']])
```

Also, due to insufficient input I do not know how the fields `Starting Location`, `Owning Organization`, `Final Organization` exists in the input csv file. So, Please edit those three fields at `line 8` in the code

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Comment: @user1829517 yw